# Laravel - How to get id for other function in controller

Tags: laravel, datatable, request, dd

I am beginner of laravel. I am involving in a small project and facing some issue. I want to get the id from the function 'getVoucher' in order to display it in my function 'index'. But I have tried my code at the below, I can't get any id from it. The dd displayed 'null' and I don't know any other solution. Any comments are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
        public function getVoucher(Request $request)
    {
        $id = $request->id;
        $voucher = Voucher::where('id','=',$id)->first();

        return $voucher;

    }

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if(session()->has('LoggedAdmin')) {
            $admin = Admin::where('id','=',session('LoggedAdmin'))->first();
            $data = [
                'LoggedAdminInfo' => $admin
            ];
        }

        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $data = Voucher::latest()->get();
            return Datatables::of($data)
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->addColumn('action', function($row){
                $btn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="Display" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-light displayRecord">Display</a>';

                $btn = $btn. '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="Edit" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-light editRecord">Edit</a>';

                $btn = $btn.' <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="Delete" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-light deleteRecord"><i class="far fa-trash-alt btn-outline-danger"></i></a>';


                return $btn;


            })
            ->rawColumns(['action'])
            ->make(true);
        }

        $voucher = $this->getVoucher($request);

        $voucherId = $voucher->id;

        dd($voucher);


        $voucherStatus = VoucherStatus::where('voucher_id','=', $voucherId)->get();

        return view('pages.voucher', $data, compact('voucherStatus'));
    }
```

Comment: Does the `$request` inside of `index` have an `id`? I see that `getVoucher` has `$request->id` but the `$request` inside `index` might not.

Comment: @Andy You mean in the blade view?  The end of the result will be displayed on a model when I clicked on it. But I still unable to make it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use self:: not $this.
like this:

```
public function getVoucher(Request $request)
    {
        $id = $request->id;
        $voucher = Voucher::where('id','=',$id)->first();

        return $voucher;

    }

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if(session()->has('LoggedAdmin')) {
            $admin = Admin::where('id','=',session('LoggedAdmin'))->first();
            $data = [
                'LoggedAdminInfo' => $admin
            ];
        }

        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $data = Voucher::latest()->get();
            return Datatables::of($data)
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->addColumn('action', function($row){
                $btn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="Display" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-light displayRecord">Display</a>';

                $btn = $btn. '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="Edit" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-light editRecord">Edit</a>';

                $btn = $btn.' <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="Delete" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-light deleteRecord"><i class="far fa-trash-alt btn-outline-danger"></i></a>';


                return $btn;


            })
            ->rawColumns(['action'])
            ->make(true);
        }

        $voucher = self::getVoucher($request);

        $voucherId = $voucher->id;

        dd($voucher);


        $voucherStatus = VoucherStatus::where('voucher_id','=', $voucherId)->get();

        return view('pages.voucher', $data, compact('voucherStatus'));
    }
```

or even better, you can do this instead:

```
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if(session()->has('LoggedAdmin')) {
            $admin = Admin::where('id','=',session('LoggedAdmin'))->first();
            $data = [
                'LoggedAdminInfo' => $admin
            ];
        }

        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $data = Voucher::latest()->get();
            return Datatables::of($data)
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->addColumn('action', function($row){
                $btn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="Display" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-light displayRecord">Display</a>';

                $btn = $btn. '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="Edit" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-light editRecord">Edit</a>';

                $btn = $btn.' <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="Delete" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-light deleteRecord"><i class="far fa-trash-alt btn-outline-danger"></i></a>';


                return $btn;


            })
            ->rawColumns(['action'])
            ->make(true);
        }

        $voucher = Voucher::find($request->id);

        $voucherId = $voucher->id;

        dd($voucher);


        $voucherStatus = VoucherStatus::where('voucher_id','=', $voucherId)->get();

        return view('pages.voucher', $data, compact('voucherStatus'));
    }
```

Comment: "you have to use self:: not $this" why? neither method is static.

Answer (score -1):

```
public function getVoucher(Request $request)
    {
        $id = $request->id;
        $voucher = Voucher::where('id','=',$id)->first();
         $this->index($voucher->id);`enter code here`
    }
    public function index(Request $request, $voucher)
    {
        if(session()->has('LoggedAdmin')) {
            $admin = Admin::where('id','=',session('LoggedAdmin'))->first();
            $data = [
                'LoggedAdminInfo' => $admin
            ];
        }

        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $data = Voucher::latest()->get();
            return Datatables::of($data)
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->addColumn('action', function($row){
                $btn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="Display" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-light displayRecord">Display</a>';

                $btn = $btn. '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="Edit" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-light editRecord">Edit</a>';

                $btn = $btn.' <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="Delete" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-light deleteRecord"><i class="far fa-trash-alt btn-outline-danger"></i></a>';


                return $btn;


            })
            ->rawColumns(['action'])
            ->make(true);
        }
        dd($voucher);
```